# VS2008 Hot Key for Specific Code Formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, code-formatting

All,
In my VS2008 C# editor window I'm trying to get from this:

```
/******** CONSTANTS ********/
const int HOLD_AWAITING_PAYMENT = 1;
const int HOLD_INT_LENDER_APPROVAL = 2;
const int HOLD_MDIA = 3;
```

to this:

```
/******** CONSTANTS ********/
const int HOLD_AWAITING_PAYMENT      = 1;
const int HOLD_INT_LENDER_APPROVAL   = 2;
const int HOLD_MDIA                  = 3;
```

I seem to remember that there's a hot key or plug-in or somethat that does this. Does anyone remember the formatting trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a macro called `LineEmUp` in VS 2008 that does exactly this.
Tools > Options > Keyboard > Show commands containing: LineEmUp

You can assign it to any key combination right there.

**Upd**: note that you have to  call it multiple times if you need to format more than one "column" in your code block.

Comment: Hey @DK, you answer it, that's exactly what I was remembering, +1!  But, the macro isn't working very well.  It moved my code around a little bit but didn't push the equals signs all way out and aligned them.  Have you used this with much success?  If I can't get it to work then I may dip my pinky toe into some VS2008 macro coding.  Or maybe a better LineEmUp macro already exists???

Comment: @sisdog, yes, I use it a lot and it works pretty good for me; and yes - there are other flavors of this macro online - the keyword to search for is LineEmUp ;) Just to double-check that we are talking about the same macro, please see this answer's [history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6795911/revisions) - I've actually posted complete macro code before realizing that this macro comes from MS itself.

Answer (score 0):

`[CTRL] + [K]` + `[CTRL] + [D]` is the default hotkey sequence to format an entire document.

However the rules regarding the formatting of the code is dependent on the settings configured in:

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > {Language} > Formatting

Comment: This does not align the code as the OP request, K,D neatens up everything. What he is looking for is align by equals. Which is CTRL + ALT + ]

Answer (score 0):

Not with the default formatting of VS. You're looking for what's called 'alignment' setting in other editors. You need to use a extension like Resharper (there are others but I can't recollect now).